# Jquery first load contents then fadein

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery to "POST" a form to a page, and the results of that should fill the DIV where the form first was.

I use this:

```
$.post('management_actions.php', $('#NewJobForm').serialize(), function(data){
  $('#JobWindow').fadeOut(150).html(data).fadeIn(150);
});
```

But it does not work, since it is already fading in before the contents are loaded. How to make the functions "wait" for each other?

Comment: You might use `.done()` too for extra certainty: `$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data);})` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use callback function like this

```
$('#JobWindow').fadeOut(150,function(){
   $('#JobWindow').html(data);
   $('#JobWindow').fadeIn(150);
});
```

this will wait for `fadeOut effect` to complete before  setting the data

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/eFPha/1/)